# Excel Formula Extract any number greater than x charters from a string

Tags: excel

I have a file which contains a list of data. In each cell is a name and number and a date the date is either mm/yy or mm-yy or mm-yyyy etc. (never the day just month and year)
The number I need is always going to be greater than 5 characters. Is there a way that I can get just the number from the string

- `xx company holding - 96923432 -02-22`. (number required 96923432)
- `yy Company (HOLDINGS) LTD - 131002204 - 02/2023` (number required 131002204)
- `ab HOLDINGS LIMITED / 115472907 / Feb-23` (number required 115472907)

Comment: You have not shown that you have tried anything. I suggest you write VBA code to use Regular Expressions in a User Defined Function. See [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Answer (score 1):

... prior removed

**=========UPDATE=========**

This formula will work for you, which splits your data by space, then converts to a number and then extracts the max. Adjust as needed if you have occasions where you may not have a number greater than 5 by wrapping with an IF().

```
=MAX(IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting since you use 2 different delimiters.  However, no worries you can simply use the following to capture both instances.  If you have more possible delimiters simply just add them between the {} in both textbefore and textafter functions.  Here is an example of the equation:`=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2, {"-","/"}), {"-","/"})`

This should work for you then if you want to return nothing if output is less than 5. `=IF(LEN(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,{"-","/"}),{"-","/"}))>5,TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,{"-","/"}),{"-","/"}),"")`

Comment: thanks sorry yes this is just an example of the data. The number could be between any number of things. I might be between .. or they might use nothing and just use a space before and after. The key for me is to be able to extract any number that is greater than a set number of characters. So any number that is greater than 5 characters for example.

Comment: sorry I think the examples are misleading. There is no delimiter. These values are created free text by different users.  so it could be xx company holding - 96923432 02-22 or it could be xx company holding 96923432 02-22 etc. The only unique factor is that it is a number that is greater than 5 characters